# Order gets lost (Javascript & Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im trying todo an automatic video creation system and have one major problem. The problem gets lost here. Program works correctly, but the output is not being printed in correct order.

```
    let fullPath = "script.txt"
fs.readFile(fullPath, 'UTF-8', async (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error("READSCRIPTERROR: " + err);
        return
    }
    let lines = data.split(/\r?\n/)
    lines.forEach(async line => {

        let res = await findimage(line)

        let filename = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000).toString();
        txtomp3.getMp3(replaceall("**", "", line)).then(async function (binaryStream) {
            let file = fs.createWriteStream("./voice/" + filename + ".mp3");
            file.write(binaryStream);
            file.end();
            voices.push("./voice/" + filename + ".mp3")
            getAudioDurationInSeconds("./voice/" + filename + ".mp3").then((duration) => {
                let dur = duration.toString().split(".")[0]
                console.log("Line" + line);
                mainImage(dur, line, filename, res)
            });
        })


    })


})
```

Everything else is working but i just do not get it to work.

In my file is

Hello1
Hello2
hello3

But after that its like random

system is printing `Test1 Hello Test2`

While it should be printing in the correct order i.e. `Hello Test1 Test2`

Comment: What do you mean with `order gets lost`. You need to describe a bit clearer what the code is expected to do, and what exactly does not work correctly.

Comment: Well it works, but it should be like from the order:

Hello
Test1
Test2

But its like

Test2
Hello
Test1

Comment: When we couldn't explain something it is either we are in love or drunk. Which one is your case?  Please show us some light so that we can learn together 

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because neither a `forEach`, nor a `.then()` call will stop the next statement/iteration from executing synchronously.

A good rule of the thumb is:

- Don't pass an `async` function as `forEach` callback; use a `for` loop instead.
- Don't mix the use of `async` and `.then()`. Choose one pattern and stick with it

Here is how you can streamline the asynchrony:

```
let fullPath = "script.txt"
fs.readFile(fullPath, 'UTF-8', async (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error("READSCRIPTERROR: " + err);
        return;
    }
    let lines = data.split(/\r?\n/);
    for (let line of lines) {
        let res = await findimage(line);
        let filename = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000).toString();
        let binaryStream = await txtomp3.getMp3(replaceall("**", "", line));
        let file = fs.createWriteStream("./voice/" + filename + ".mp3");
        file.write(binaryStream);
        file.end();
        voices.push("./voice/" + filename + ".mp3");
        let duration = await getAudioDurationInSeconds("./voice/" + filename + ".mp3");
        let dur = duration.toString().split(".")[0];
        console.log("Line" + line);
        mainImage(dur, line, filename, res);        
    }
});
```

This assumes that the functions that you have not provided, work as intended. For instance, if `mainImage` is a function that has asynchronous behaviour and returns a promise, then you should also use `await` with it.